# Python3: how to slice a list to two part in a loop, one is 20%, the left is another part

Tags: list, python-3.x, slice

Hi I want to slice a large list data like the following list, one part is 20%(consecutive) part of the list, another is left. I just know to get the 20% part but how to get the left part of list in a loop. Thanks my code is following.
for example, when X1 = [ '1', '2'], X2 = ['3','4','5','6', 7','8','9','10']. then
X1 = ['2','3'], and X2 =  ['1','4','5','6', 7','8','9','10'], .........

```
X = ['1','2','3','4','5','6', 7','8','9','10']
index = 0
for i in range(9):
     X1 = X[i:(i+2)]
     X2 = X[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the second part by telling from what index you would like to start untill the end.

```
X = ['1','2','3','4','5','7','8','9','10']
index = 0
for i in range(9):
     X1 = X[i:(i+2)]
     X2 = X[:i] + X[(i+2):]
```

Comment: thanks for your comments, sorry for my missing some information about my question, and I have updated my questions

Comment: @tktktk0711 , Now it's more clear :) In that case you can do what I did in my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to offer a similar, but more robust solution. You say you need to get 20% of the large list. While slice size of 2 works for a list with 9 members, you will obviously need to increase it for a larger list. If you do not know how many members a list will have, it can be particularly tedious and error prone. Hence, I would suggest something like this:

```
import math

X = ['1','2','3','4','5','7','8','9','10']
# Calculate how many members a 20% slice should have
twenty = int(math.ceil(len(X) *  20 / 100.0))

for i in range(len(X)):
     X1 = X[i:(i+twenty)]
     X2 = X[:i] + X[(i+twenty):]
```

What this does is calculate how many members ~20% slice should have, and then apply this number to list slicing. Note, however, that [`math.ceil()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/math.html#math.ceil) always rounds *up*, so if you have something like 2.1, it would end up being 3.0 (meaning that some slices will have slightly more members than 20%, e.g. 22%). If you want to round in a more familiar fashion (2.49 -> 2; 2.5 -> 3), [round()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#round) would be a good choice.